# which account IIS uses to run asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-2.0, cassini

Any idea which account IIS uses to run asp.net project. My project or code access file which is in C:\path\path directory. When I test the project in my machine it runs fine (well I am running in built server; Cassini) but when I test the same project in development server where it uses IIS 6.0 ... my code throws a exception "Access to the file C:\path\path is denied".

Not sure how can I solve this? any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the identity used by the application pool your web application runs under.  Here are steps for IIS 6:

1. Click **Start | Run...**
2. Type **inetmgr**, click **OK**
3. In the left-hand pane of **IIS Manager**, browse to your web application, e.g., ***My Server* | Web Sites | Default Web Site | *My Web App***
4. Right-click on the web application, click **Properties**
5. In the general tab, note name of the the selected **Application pool**.  Click **Cancel**
6. Go back to the left-hand pane of **IIS Manager**.  Browse to ***My Server* | Application Pools | *My Application Pool***, where *My Application Pool* is the name you found in step 5, above.
7. Right-click on ***My Application Pool***, click **Properties**
8. Click on the **Identity** tab.  This shows the identity that your web application is running under.

Answer (score 1):

Use the IIS Manager to verify which *Application Pool* that is running the site you want to investigate.

If you look at the properties for the Application Pool, there is a tab named *Identity* in which you can determine what user is set to run the process.

You can also use the Task Manager to see which user is running the process named `w3wp.exe`, which is a process running an instance of IIS (or an Application Pool, in fact).